# Remove an item from shopping basket PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a shopping basket using PHP, I can add items, clear the whole basket however I am stuck when trying to remove just one item from the basket. I try to send a GET variable into the URL and then decrease the quantity of the specified item based on it's ID. Although at the moment it doesn't seem to work and if I click multiple times the URL gets huge and the GET variables keep getting added to the end rather than changing the whole URL.

Here is my PHP

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value) {
               $ids .= $id . ',';

               $count += $value['quantity'];

               $totalPrice += $value['price'];

            } 

             $query = $database->find_item_db($ids);

            foreach ($query as $single_query) {
                $id = $single_query['Sweet_ID'];
            echo $single_query['Description']; ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] . '<a href=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'&idToRemove=' . $id . '&action=remove> Remove </a>' . '</br>';
            } ?>

        <h3>Currently <?php echo $count; ?> Items in the basket</h3>
        <h4> Total Price £<?php echo $totalPrice; ?> </h4>

        <?php
          } else {
            echo "Your cart is empty";
          }
    ?> 


<?php
session_start();

if ($_GET['action'] == "add") {

    $idNumber=intval($_GET['id']); 

    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$idNumber])) {

        $_SESSION['cart'][$idNumber]['quantity']++;

    } else {
        $sql = $database->display_single($idNumber);

        $second_id = $sql[0]['Sweet_ID'];
        $price = $sql[0]['Price'];

        $_SESSION['cart'][$second_id]=array(
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price"   => $price
        );
    }

} else if ($GET['action'] == 'remove') {

    $idNumber=intval($_GET['idToRemove']); 

    $_SESSION['cart'][$idNumber]['quantity']--;

}  else if ($_GET['action'] == 'clear') {
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}

?>
```

Comment: First thing I notice: You start the session after the headers were sent and use it before initialized. Then syntax, style and used functions do not look secure, looks like XSS vuln to me, and I guess also SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
'<a href=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'&idToRemove=' . $id . '&action=remove> Remove </a>'
```

into this:

```
'<a href="?idToRemove=' . $id . '&action=remove"> Remove </a>'
```

as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` already contains all the parameters that are currently present in the URL.
This will create a blank URL (pointing to the current page) with only the `idToRemove` and `action` parameters.

(And add double quotes, to keep the URL nicely contained within the `href` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your HTML code.
I think you have something like this in your PHP :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>"
```

And as you always (re)call the same HTML form, the previous posted GET vars a posted again and again ....

Answer (score 0):

I've programmed a basket class based on session you can use it , any question ask me please

```
class basket {
function add($pid,$qty){


if(!isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
$_SESSION['basket']=array();
$_SESSION['basket'][0]['productid']=$pid;
$_SESSION['basket'][0]['qty']=$qty;
echo 'The product was successfully added';
}

else {

if($this->isexist($pid,$qty)){
echo 'The quantity was successfully updated';
}
else{
$m=$_SESSION['basket'];
$max=count($m);
$_SESSION['basket'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
$_SESSION['basket'][$max]['qty']=$qty;
echo 'The product was successfully added';
}
}

}

function isexist($pid,$qty) {
$m=$_SESSION['basket'];
$max=count($m);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
if($pid==$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['productid']){
$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['qty']=$qty;
return true;break;}
}
return false;}

function delete($pid){
$m=$_SESSION['basket'];
$max=count($m);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
if($pid==$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['productid']){
unset($_SESSION['basket'][$i]);
$_SESSION['basket']=array_values($_SESSION['basket']);
$_SESSION['basket'.'num']-=1;echo 'The product was successfully delete';
break;}
}
}


function modify($pid,$qty){
$m=$_SESSION['basket'];
$max=count($m);
if($qty>0){
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
if($pid==$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['productid']){
$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['qty']=$qty;break;}
}
}
else $this->delete($pid);


}

function show_basket() {

$max=count($_SESSION['basket']);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
echo 'id=>'.$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['productid'].'qty=>'.$_SESSION['basket'][$i]['qty'];
}
}

}
```

Comment: I will take a look at this, looks clean